# How does Room verify data integrity? Where are the db versions/hashes stored?

Tags: java, android, android-room

My goal is to use Room's new createFromAsset api to load a pre-loaded database from the apps assets. However, I noticed that if my pre-loaded database does not have a organic (generated by Room) id and identity hash in the `room_master_table`, I get a "IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify the data integrity." exception thrown.

I have tried using an exact db file generated by Room as a pre-loaded db that it copies over and this works, but I am not sure why. It seems like these database version/id/hashes are saved somewhere and Room validates it against these versions. But I have tried deleting the local db and uninstalling the app as well but still get the same exception thrown.

I'd like to know how room generates a specific id and hash in `room_master_table` and how does it validate them?

Comment: I suggest you don't include the `room_master_table` in your pre-package database. When opening the database for the first time, Room will validate the schema and create the master table along with the hash if all looks good. If you include the `room_master_table` then it will seem as if the database had been already opened by Room in which case Room will just compare hashes instead of doing a more appropriate schema check.

Comment: @DanyBoricua thats not correct. Whether or not you provide `room_master_table` room will do the same thing. It calls `SELECT identity_hash FROM room_master_table` all the time independent of you providing `room_master_table` or not. And then it compares to returned value (`null` if not exists) with a compiled hash.

Comment: @musooff, that is not my understanding based on Room's OpenHelper (where the master table is checked). See: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/room/runtime/src/main/java/androidx/room/RoomOpenHelper.java#141

Comment: @DanyBoricua as you have pointed out from source code. It checks for a `identity_has` within `room_master_table` not existence of `room_master_table`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Room Persistence Library generates unique `identity_hash` for every version of database. And it is stored at `room_master_table`.

Every time you compile your application room generates `mIdentityHash` reflecting your current database schema. And whenever you run application and call database for the first time *Room* compares it to the `mLegacyHash` which is already stored in database. So if these two hashes are different,  `Room` throws `IlligalStateException`.

All of these processes done with *Annotation Processing Library* that you add into your *build.gradle* file with

```
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
// annotationProcessing androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version in case you use Java
```

You can check *Room* [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/room) for detailed verification. Take a look at [`RoomOpenHelper.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/room/runtime/src/main/java/androidx/room/RoomOpenHelper.java) class which has `checkIdentity()` function where they check `identity_hash` and throw exception if two **identity hashes** don't match.

If you are looking for how exactly `identity_key` is generated take a look at [`SchemaIdentityKey.kt`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/room/compiler/src/main/kotlin/androidx/room/vo/SchemaIdentityKey.kt)

I hope it was helpful.

Comment: When you mention the `mLegacyHash`, is that the `identity_hash` currently in the database?

Comment: @Dan Yes. `mLegacyHash` is the one already exists and `mItendityHash` is the one it generates with new code

Comment: This is old post but let me clarify this as the statement below is in correct. `And whenever you run application and call database for the first time Room compares it to the mLegacyHash which is already stored in database.`  mLegacyHash is just another hash for same table which was using Room V1 library. So condition is just as below. If either one matches, it works. `if(this.identityHash != identityHash && this.legacyHash != identityHash) {`